# How to fix page jumping up when scrolled to bottom on IOS mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js

I used Vue to create my site and desktop version works perfect. When tested on Mobile IOS Safari and Chrome the page jumps up a bit when scrolled to bottom the first time. Android works fine. This problem doesn't happen the second time you scroll to bottom before you refresh the page. This problem also won't happen if you test it on desktop through dev tools.

The site's profile page does not have this problem.

I made a screen recording of the behavior: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B93xtwF8f2VWAVegLbsZFULn3TymUCNZ/view?usp=sharing

I converted all the vh values to px to prevent browser reflow like so
`let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh',`${vh}px`);`
it fixed my layout but didn't help with the jumping problem.

I also tried to set up a fixed height to the body by assigning CSS height values through Jquery .css method, when the fixed height is taller than the actual content, this problem does not happen.

I'm sorry that I don't have a snippet to reproduce this problem, I have no idea where the problem is at all.
My site url is https://www.jingqi.work

The expected result would be without the jumping up movement when scrolled to bottom, basically like how the profile page behaves.